# AVAudioPlayer doesn't play audio

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I am trying to play a mp3 file but not playing. There is no error. Just not playing.

I've imported necessary files:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

And this is my code:

```
NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/music.mp3", documentsDirectory];

    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:&error];
    player.numberOfLoops = -1; //Infinite
    player.volume=1;
    player.delegate=self;
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];
```

Nothing is wrong with mp3 file. I can play it on my iPhone's player but not playing on my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of things you have to watch out for with AVAudioPlayer is that if it has to remain allocated while playing.  If you make AVAudioPlayer *player an ivar I think your problem will go away.